# Does Manifestation of Wrath heal depending on the number of enemies hit or not?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The power says:

> Daily        Divine, Radiant
>
> Standard Action      Close burst 1
>
> Target: Each enemy in the burst
>
> Effect: Each target takes 10 + Wisdom modifier radiant damage, and you
>   gain that number of temporary hit points. Until the end of the
>   encounter, you gain a +2 power bonus to attack rolls

As the Dungeon master, I told my player the power says "that number" referring to the damage dealt to one enemy. He says its a 15 cleric level power and is potential should be 10 + Wis (9) = 19 * 8 enemies (assuming he has 8 enemies adjacent) = 152 damage and 152 temporary hit points..

Really too much in my opinion (I don't remember a power giving 150 temporary hit points...)

My simple question is: "that number of temporary hit points" means all the damage dealt to all enemies or 10 + Wis?

Comment: Practically speaking how many enemies are ever adjacent to the cleric in a typical encounter? Two perhaps? At most three?

Answer (score 4):

**10 + Wis**

> Each target takes 10 + Wisdom modifier radiant damage, and you gain *that number* of temporary hit points.

I think it is quite clear, every enemy gets 19 damage, so "that number" is 19. You get 19 THP. It is really weak indeed, but there are several great powers for clerics on that level, like  Tree of Creation.

If you were to get THP from each enemy, it would be phrased like this:

> 1[W] + Strength modifier damage. You gain 5 temporary hit points for **each** target hit by the attack.

(Strength from Valor, paladin 3)

Comment: Keep in mind you're comparing a level 15 daily to a level 3 encounter power (where you're arguing the level 3 provides potentially more hps and the basically the same amount of damage)...

Comment: The question was about what it says, not what it should or could say. The level is not relevant, Strength of Valor was just an example for the wording.

Comment: @UtherTG: I would say you do get 10+Wis THP only once, but the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules as they are written, each enemy suffers the damage and you gain the damage in temporary hit points. I don't see any other way to read this.

---

The fact that the player is within range of 8 targets does not mean the ability should be brought into question - this is a dangerous situation, AOE powers are great to use here, and the temporary hit points probably wont last long. You as the dungeon master are in charge of the encounters.

In my opinion a 15th level Cleric who is surrounded by 8 enemies should definitely be able to use a power that he can use only once a day to grant himself extra life, deal damage, and gain a bonus to attack. Why should that seem overpowered?

Why would you deny your player the benefit of such a great use of his power?

Comment: Temporary hit points are not commulative, unless the power specifically says so.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with InbarRose.